# Get file path from assets url

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest` to send an image to a server inside a POST HTTP Request.
That image is saved into the phone gallery, and I can get it and display it using its "assets url", which is something like this:
assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=F2B91A20-615E-4E88-B9AF-8D209A587505&ext=PNG

But my problem is that I don't want to load the whole image in memory to send it, so I would like to use it's REAL url to get it and send it.

This is my code:

```
- (void)startPostWithMedia
{   
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@", @"12345"];
    NSString * fullContentType = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@;boundary=%@", contentType, stringBoundary];

    [request addRequestHeader:CONTENT_TYPE_HDR value:fullContentType];

    [request appendPostDataFromFile:[mediaUrl absoluteString]];

    [self retain];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

The main problem is, when I use `appendPostDataFromFile:` using the assets url, this assets url does not return the image, just return nil and it does not work.

I need to get the real file path of that image to use it, not the assets url.

In some post I've found here, I've seen that you cannot get the actual file-path from the AssetsLibrary because of sandboxing, so... How could I solve it???

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: To access phone gallery, use UIImagePickerController. In the respective delegate, you will find the image path.

Comment: What I get there is the assets path...not what I'm asked here.

Comment: Then take image from asset URL, store it on some known location, share the path of that URL.

Comment: make a custom path instead

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, your options are really pretty limited.  Sandboxing prevents you from getting a "real" file:/// url.  Your only option is really to read the image into memory (and optionally write it into the application documents or temporary folders)  By making a copy of the file you do at least reduce the long-term memory usage, although the short-term usage is still high.